# make text double bold - scaled sheets

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, react-native

Is there any way to increase the intensity of the bold-ness of apply it twice?

I am using this styling on my text:

```
  numbers: {
    fontSize: 30,
    color: '#31C283',
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
```

Is it possible to make it double/more bold without increasing the font size?

Comment: Bold is not an operation like font size. Actually when you create a font you create a normal, an italic one and a bold one.

Comment: you can use a custom font and use https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/font-family to have an effectlike this.

Comment: try `fontWeight: '900'` [Font Weight](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp) can take numerical values.

Comment: this page explain it : https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

Answer (score 2):

You can slightly adjust the thickness by setting numerical values at the property `fontWeight`.

Besides `bold` the property `fontWeight` can also handle numerical values, such as `100` for very thin and `900` for very thick.

As far as I know, `fontWeight: 'bold'` has the numerical value `fontWeight: '700'`.

So:

`fontWeight: '900'` should be slightly thicker than `fontWeight: 'bold'`

Well, it's not the "double" what you actually ask for, but maybe this helps you a bit.

Source: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_weight.asp

---

If you want to have a text "bolder" than `fontWeight: '900'` you will have to use "visual cheats", e. g. another font-family or text-shadow.

Here is some sample:

```html
<div style="font-weight:900;">I am the highest font-weight value 900</div>
<div class="doublethick">But I am even thicker :)</div>

<style>
.doublethick {
 color:#000000;    
 text-shadow: 0.5px 0 #000000;
 letter-spacing:1px;
 font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use text shadow property like this

```html
<h1 style="text-shadow: 2px 0px 1px #000;">This is h1 tag</h1>
```

Answer (score 1):

For making a number double bold you can use this code

```
numbers: {
   font-size: 30;
   color: hex;
   font-weight: 800;
}
```

I think it will work.